# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in captions

Tags: captions, underfull

I have quite a big document and got an `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warning at each and every caption I have in a figure, subfigure or table. I didn't find any notes about similar problems and I have no idea what could cause this. Maybe someone has an answer on this?
I am coding in overleaf, if this makes a difference.

Here is a example of what I mean:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12pt,
  openany,
  twoside=false,
  headsepline=true,
  numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[ngerman,silent]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{ziffer}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[locale=DE,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{leftidx}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[NewCommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[german]{rccol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nogroupskip,section=subsection]{glossaries}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage[americaninductors, straightvoltages, european resistors, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma, 1000 sep={\,}}

\usepackage[
  final,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  linktoc=all,
  hidelinks
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[ngerman,noabbrev,sort,compress]{cleveref} 
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \input{Falschstrom_Kabel.tex}
    \caption{Falschstromkennlinie des Kabels}
    \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Falschstrom_Kabel.tex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width = 0.9\textwidth,
      height = 0.3\textheight,
    ]        
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: There could be tens of reasons for that. To be able to help, try to prepare a file showing the problem --- if it happens for every figure, it will suffice a file with just one figure *and* the preamble code that creates the problem.

Comment: I added my preamble and a figure as an example.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it looks like the problem boils down to `\usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage[NewCommands]{ragged2e}`.  (Also, this isn't really an overleaf problem, so that tag should be removed.)

Comment: Are you sure you need *all* those packages to produce the problem? It would be nice if you try to trim it down...

Answer (score 1):

A real **minimal** code showing the problem is the following one(Note 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[NewCommands]{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \fbox{\Huge\strut image here}
    \caption{Falschstromkennlinie des Kabels}
    \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It seems that the problem is the `[NewCommands]` option for the `ragged2e` package. If you remove it, there is no more "underfull hbox" warning. Why this is happening, I do not know --- but the `NewCommand` option changes the original LaTeX commands and it seems that `\caption` is expecting something different from them.

---

Note 1: I copied your huge example, and removed (binary search) all packages until I found the minimal example showing the problem. Please, repeat this process next time!